# Properly use a loop in coroutine to place rest api call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I am currently building a Flickr-like app and I do have a question about pagination.

I am currently calling a FlickrApi to retrieve the recent photos. It's working well but I only get the first 100 because the api only returned list of photos using `page` so it avoid to have 10000 photos in one call.

The JSON returned look like this:

```
{
   "photos": { 
   "page": 1,
   "pages": 10,
   "perpage": 100,
   "total": 1000,
   "photo": [...]
```

My repository to call the api look like this:

```
    override suspend fun getRecentPhotos(): FlickrResult<FlickrPhotosList?> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        when (val response = flickrApiHelper.getRecentPhotos()) {
            is FlickrApiResult.OnSuccess -> {
                FlickrResult.OnSuccess(
                    FlickrMapper.fromRetrofitToFlickrPhotosList(response.data)
                )
            }

            is FlickrApiResult.OnError -> {
                FlickrResult.OnError(
                    response.exception
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

and the interface is :

```
interface FlickrApiHelper {
    suspend fun getRecentPhotos(page: Int = 1): FlickrApiResult<RetrofitPhotosItem>
}
```

the viewModel is done like below:

```
fun getRecentPhotos() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _flickerPhotoState.value = FlickrState.Loading
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                when(val result = flickrUseCases.getRecentPhotos()) {
                    is FlickrResult.OnSuccess -> {
                        result.data?.photo?.let {
                            if(it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                _flickerPhotoState.value = FlickrState.DisplayPhotos(
                                    Mapper.fromListFlickrPhotoItemToListPhotoDetails(it)
                                )
                            } else {
                               _flickerPhotoState.value = FlickrState.NoPhotos
                            }
                            return@withContext
                        }
                        _flickerPhotoState.value = FlickrState.NoPhotos
                    }

                    is FlickrResult.OnError -> {
                        _flickerPhotoState.value = FlickrState.Error(result.exception)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve to add a loop and place successive call to get page 2, 3....

I cannot figure-out a good way to plug the loop. My goal is really to place a call, update UI through state flow, place a call to next page, add to UI..

I would prefer to do it in the repository rather than the viewModel, but I am not sure what is the best place.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want to load every page proactively? How does the API indicate when the last page is reached?

Comment: @Tenfour04 The Api send the total number of page. So I can compare current page vs total page.

Comment: So I know when to stop but I am not sure how to properly call without having a crazy loop

Comment: What is `getRecentPhotos()` in the repository overriding? You said you want to update the UI even as it is still fetching new pages, so a suspend function isn't appropriate--it should be a flow. But if you have to override something, you're kind of stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Preface: `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` is unnecessary for calling suspend functions. It is only needed for wrapping *blocking* function calls. I'm assuming your implementation of the FlickrApiHelper suspend function is defined properly so it doesn't block--suspend functions should never block.

You described wanting to update the UI as the pages continue to be retrieved, so what you need to expose is a Flow, not a suspend function. Assuming you can change the definition of whatever interface/abstract function you are overriding in your repository, you can change it to a Flow that looks like this:

```
private val recentPhotosPages: Flow<FlickrResult<FlickrPhotosList?>> = flow {
    var numPages = -1
    var page = 1
    while (numPages < 0 || page <= numPages) {
        when (val response = flickrApiHelper.getRecentPhotos(page)) {
            is FlickrApiResult.OnSuccess -> {
                if (numPages < 0) {
                    numPages = reponse.data?.pages ?: 0 // my guess at how to retrieve page count, adjust accordingly
                }
                FlickrResult.OnSuccess(
                    FlickrMapper.fromRetrofitToFlickrPhotosList(response.data)
                )
            }

            is FlickrApiResult.OnError -> {
                FlickrResult.OnError(
                    response.exception
                )
            }
        }.let { emit(it) }

        if (numPages < 0) {
            return@flow // error on first page retrieval, give up
        }
        page++
    }
}

override val recentPhotosCumulative: Flow<List<FlickrResult<FlickrPhotosList?>>> = recentPhotosPages
    .runningFold<List<FlickrResult<FlickrPhotosList?>>>(emptyList()) { acc, result ->
        acc + result
    }
    .drop(1) // Drop the initial empty emission from runningFold, 
             // otherwise the Loading state in ViewModel's flow would never appear.
```

I'm using a List that concatenates your FlickrResults from each call. This results in a List of objects containing Lists, which is convoluted to deal with in the ViewModel, so you might want to come up with a different class to represent all your pages put together and use that type instead.

Then in your ViewModel you would probably want to expose a SharedFlow. We can base it off of a private `SharedFlow<Unit>` to enable the ability to refresh on demand.

```
private val recentPhotosInitiator = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1)
    .also { tryEmit(Unit) }

val flickerPhotoState = recentPhotosInitiator
    .transformLatest {
        emit(FlickrState.Loading)
        flickrUseCases.recentPhotosCumulative.map { listOfFlickrResults ->
            // These incoming results are the concatenated results for you to deal
            // with accordingly. As mentioned above, this is a convoluted nested list unless
            // you create a class to represent the result with concatenated list of pages.

            // This lambda should return a FlickrState.DisplayPhotos or NoPhotos or Error
            // if I understand your original code correctly
        }.let { emitAll(it) }
    }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1)


// Call this if you want to clear the flow and start loading from scratch again
fun refreshPhotoState() {
    recentPhotosInitiator.tryEmit(Unit)
}
```